# Setting an empty default value for a char-column in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin I have a char(32) column that has no default value(ie. Default: None). When I try to insert data through a SQL query, it throws out an error saying that the column "doesn't have a default value". I need it to be empty, so instead I've just set it's default value as "As defined: " and then nothing in the value field. Is this a bad idea?

And is it any better than simply throwing in an empty value for the column in the SQL query?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to insert a row that does not have some columns defined. These columns may either be `NULL` or a defined default value. It is up to you to decide what action to take when no data is provided for a column - do you want it to be NULL (i.e. empty) or a defined value?

Comment: I've heard that NULL takes up more space than an empty value, is that true?